# WebSphere 8.5: unit testing & embeddable container

Tags: java, maven, ejb, websphere-8, embedded-container

I'm trying to run the following unit test in a Maven project using a WebSphere 8.5 embeddable container:

```
import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;

...

private EJBContainer ec;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    properties.put(EJBContainer.PROVIDER, "com.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.EmbeddableContainerProvider");

    ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
}

@Test
public void test1(){
...
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception in the setup method:

> CNTR9403E: The embeddable enterprise bean container cannot start
>   multiple modules with the same file name: project1\target\classes and
>   project2\target\classes

Does anybody know how to get around this issue? I searched but couldn't find anything useful.

**Edit:**
I've found the documentation for the exception CNTR9403E here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.messages.doc%2Fcom.ibm.ejs.container.container.html

> CNTR9403E: The embeddable enterprise bean container cannot start
>   multiple modules with the same file name: {0} and {1}
>
> ```
> Explanation   User code has directed the embeddable container to start multiple modules with the same file name.
> Action    Specify a list of modules that does not have duplicate file names, or rename one of the modules with a unique file name.
> ```

But I don't see how I can fix this. Is it complaining about the two "classes" directories at the end of the paths? How can I solve this in a Maven multi-module project? Or is it a bug in WebSphere 8.5?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `classes` directory name is causing the conflict.  There is no workaround for using those directory names, so I would recommend testing the generated `.jar` instead, though I have no expertise with Maven, so I don't know how feasible that is.  This is somewhat unsatisfactory, so you could open a [WebSphere RFE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181) to allow properties to be specified to disambiguate.